# Woocommerce check if coupon is valid or been used

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, coupon

how can i check is the coupon is valid or been used? I have a this code:

`if (is_page('checkout')){
//check coupon insert first is valid or no
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 2 methods on WC_cart object regarding applied coupons:

```
$applied_coupons = WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons();
```

Return an array of applied coupons codes

And:

```
if( WC()->cart->has_discount( 'your_coupon_code' ) && is_checkout() ) {
    // do something
}
```

Returns whether or not a discount has been applied (boolean).

> Note: The correct conditionals in woocommerce for targeting cart or checkout pages are **`is_checkout()`** for checkout page and  **`is_cart()`** for cart page.

References:

- [WooCommerce Class WC_Cart - Methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#_has_discount)
- [WooCommerce Conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#cart-page)